# How to join multiple variables using underscore

Tags: github, github-actions

I wish to add the three variables `steps.Deployment.outputs.newCO`, `steps.Deployment.outputs.formatdate` and `github.run_number` using underscore `_`. I tried:

```
  - name: Call composite
    id: fixit
    uses: mybank/DevOps/integration@master
    with:
      ArrCall: '${{ inputs.backup_fileextension || {steps.Deployment.outputs.newCO}_{steps.Deployment.outputs.formatdate}_{github.run_number} }}'
```

The attempt gives the below error:

```
Invalid workflow file: .github/workflows/main.yml#L206
The workflow is not valid. In .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 206, Col: 11): Error from called workflow mybank/DevOps/.github/workflows/deploy.yml@master (Line: 563, Col: 29): Unexpected symbol: '{steps'. Located at position 32 within the expression: inputs.backup_fileextension || {steps.Deployment.outputs.newCO}_{steps.Deployment.outputs.formatdate}_{github.run_number}
```

I also tried:

```yaml
ArrCall: '${{ inputs.backup_fileextension || steps.Deployment.outputs.newCO + "_" + steps.Deployment.outputs.formatdate + "_" + github.run_number }}'
```

Comment: `+` is also not in the list of operators I already pointed you to. But there are some [functions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#functions). Read the fine manual, don't just guess random syntax!

Comment: @jonrsharpe i tried to use join function but seems I m not getting the syntax correct or I may have to declare powershell variable for each variable and then use join. here's what I tried and failed: `ArrCall: '${{ inputs.backup_fileextension || join([steps.Deployment.outputs.newCO, steps.Deployment.outputs.formatdate, github.run_number], "_") }}'`     error: unexpected symbol '['

Comment: @jonrsharpe i also tried writing a new step to join the variables but the workflow errors at `$result = "${{ join([var1, var2, var3], '_') }}"` and that gives me error: `Unexpected symbol '['` where `$var1 = ${{ steps.Deployment.outputs.newCO }} $var2 = ${{ steps.Deployment.outputs.formatdate }} and $var3 = ${{ github.run_number }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `run` step to set the value as an output, using shell string concatenation:

```yaml
- name: Set param
  id: set
  env:
    co: ${{ steps.Deployment.outputs.newCO }}
    date: ${{ steps.Deployment.outputs.formatdate }}
    runno: ${{ github.run_number }}
  run: |
    echo "val=${co}_${date}_$runno" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

- name: Call composite
  id: fixit
  uses: mybank/DevOps/integration@master
  with:
    ArrCall: ${{ steps.set.outputs.val }}
```

Or you could use [`format`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#format):

```yaml
- name: Call composite
  id: fixit
  uses: mybank/DevOps/integration@master
  with:
    ArrCall: >
      ${{ format('{0}_{1}_{2}',
        steps.Deployment.outputs.newCO,
        steps.Deployment.outputs.formatdate,
        github.run_number) }}
```

Comment: can you use the `join` function as well if u include that in your example? My attempt failed to run for `join` function @benjaminW

Comment: @Ashar `join` is to join arrays, and I don't think it's possible to create an array directly in an expression.

Comment: @Ashar guess where you can find that arrays aren't a supported kind of literal: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#literals

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Typo. Redundant colon after `echo`.

Comment: @Azeem Oh whoops, thanks! Feel free to fix these directly, if you prefer.